# If $pqp = p$ and $qpq=q$, is it true that $p=q?$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $p,q \in A$ projections in $A$ with the property
$$pqp = p, \quad qpq = q.$$
I am trying to show that $p=q$, but I don't really see why this should be the case. The obvious algebraic manipulations don't seem to work. Of course, we can WLOG assume that $A= B(H)$.

This question occurs because I'm trying to justify a step in the proof of Takesaki's first volume (chapter III, theorem 4.2, p141 below, where they deduce that $q= q_1$ from the equalities $q= qq_1q$ and $q_1 = q_1qq_1$).

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways, i think here is one: $pq$ is a projection, which is the identity on the image of $p$. So $pq$ projects onto a subspace larger than the image of $p$. But the image of $pq$ is small than the image of $p$, so $p=pq$. The same way, we have $qp=q$. These two equations imply $\ker(q) = \ker(p)$. So $p=q$.

Comment: @JulianQuast $pq$ is directly seen to be an idempotent, but it is not obvious from the hypotheses that $pq$ is self-adjoint, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I also tried this way, but I also had trouble showing that $pq = (pq)^*$, which is equivalent to $pq = qp$ (and if we knew this, then we wouldn't have to prove anything).

Comment: Why do you need it to be self-adjoint? They are just idempotents and define a continuous projection. Or am I missing something? I know algebra, but not too much about $C^*$-algebras

Comment: @JulianQuast Projections in a $C^*$-algebra are by definition self-adjoint (at least, idempotents are not nearly that much used).

Comment: Okay, but an idempotent is determined by its image, whether it's self-adjoint or not? So my argument should work.

Comment: @JulianQuast It isn't! You can take two different idempotents that have the same image (for example, an orthogonal and a non-orthogonal projection on a proper non-zero subspace).

Comment: I see! We really need self-adjointness here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $0=p-pqp=p(1-q)p=(p(1-q))\cdot(p(1-q))^*$ and therefore by the $C^*$-identity we have $p(1-q)=0$, so $p=pq$. This is equivalent to $p\le q$. Likewise, since $0=q-qpq=q(1-p)q$, we get $q(1-p)=0$, qo $q=qp$ and thus $q\le p$. These two combined give $p=q$.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed the first line.